# rendering a display list produced from a pdf file

Tags: pdf, fonts, accessibility

Is there a (unix) pdf viewer that supports font substitution? This option may be useful for disabled (e.g. dyslexic) people.

For example, is there a way to render a "display list" like the following one produced by mupdf,  and *modify/substitute* the fonts?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<document name="foobar.pdf">
<page number="1">
<fill_text font="RBRYXK+CMR17" wmode="0" colorspace="DeviceGray" color="0" matrix="1 0 0 1 0 0" trm="17.2154 0 0 17.2154" >
<g ucs="S" gid="10" x="128.335" y="664.286" />
<g ucs="t" gid="24" x="137.115" y="664.286" />
<g ucs="r" gid="22" x="143.209" y="664.286" />
<g ucs="u" gid="25" x="149.303" y="664.286" />
```

I understand that  the MMZAAW+ syntax is an Adobe convention for naming font subsets. Thus this is a specific subset of CMR10, and the FontDescriptor has some useful info  (section 5.7 of the PDF spec). But many of these are optional (even if strongly recommended). FontFamily is one, but less common are FontWeight and FontStretch.    ItallicAngle is usually present, and StemV StemH can be used to infer weight. PDF also has a "Widths" array that is required and useful in font substiution. (This is taken from #ghostript irc channel of mupdf; the display list is generated by the mupdf viewer). Is there a library which can convert these font descriptions to their parameters like FontWeight, FontStretch, ItallicAngle, StemV Stem H ? Which can produce bounding boxes on these data ?

Answer (score 0):

Use PDF-a as an default PDF file type. The users PDF viewer can then render selected fonts and font-sizes as specified by the user.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/A